# Are there always nontrivial real solutions to $A_1 x^5 + B_1 y^5 + C_1 z^5 = 0$ and $A_2 x + B_2 y + C_2 z = 0$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Firstly, are there always nontrivial real solutions to the sysytem
of equations, $A_{1}x^{5}+B_{1}y^{5}+C_{1}z^{5}=0$ and $A_{2}x+B_{2}y+C_{2}z=0$,
for real numbers $A_{1}$, $B_{1}$, $C_{1}$, $A_{2}$, $B_{2}$,
and $C_{2}$? [Answered]

Secondly, are there always nontrivial real solutions to the sysytem
of equations, $A_{1}\frac{x^{5}}{\left|x\right|}+B_{1}\frac{y^{5}}{\left|y\right|}+C_{1}\frac{z^{5}}{\left|z\right|}=0$
and $A_{2}x+B_{2}y+C_{2}z=0$, for real numbers $A_{1}$, $B_{1}$,
$C_{1}$, $A_{2}$, $B_{2}$, and $C_{2}$? [Answered]

Comment: Why not title this something like "Are there always nontrivial real solutions to $A_{1}x^{5}+B_{1}y^{5}+C_{1}z^{5}=0$ and $A_{2}x+B_{2}y+C_{2}z=0$ ?" 

Comment: jc, yeah, your title would be better.

Comment: You can edit the title of your question.

Comment: Joel, your are right. It would be simpler to state the question in your way.

Comment: I changed the title per jc's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality, let $A_2\neq0$.  Then we have $x=-\frac{B_2}{A_2}y-\frac{C_2}{A_2}z$.  Thus we can eliminate $x$ from the first equation to get a degree 5 equation describing a plane curve in $y$ and $z$.

<strike>By [Harnack's curve theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_curve_theorem), the number of components of this curve in the real projective plane is between 1 and 7.  Thus you should expect at least one family of solutions to your equations.</strike> This paragraph was nonsense because what one really has at this point is an equation relating points on the projective *line*.

**See Karl Schwede's comment or Qiaochu Yuan's answer for a correct characterization**.

Note that their arguments extend to the second question as well.  Again, we can look at the $y=1$ slice of the equation we get on eliminating $x$, something like:

$$1+C_1\frac{z^5}{|z|}+\frac{(-B_2-C_2z)^5}{|-B_2-C_2z|}=0.$$

where I've scaled out $A_1,A_2,B_1$.  For large positive $z$ and large negative $z$ the function on the left will take opposite signs (which sign is taken will depend on the signs and relative magnitudes of $C_1$ and $C_2$), so you must have at least one root in between.

In the first question, your solutions typically end up as lines through the origin because the homogeneous equation in $y$ and $z$ can be rewritten as one for $y/z$.  This doesn't work in your second question and you get much more interesting looking curves (the ordinate is $z$ and the abscissa is $y$):

[image: Solution curves]

Comment: jc, thank you for the answer. It looks very much like an AG question, but I think there should be an explanation without using AG results or AG language.

Comment: Ok, let's make it simple.  As said before, plug in $x$, get a degree 5 homogenous expression $f$ in two variables $y$ and $z$.  Expand this expression.

Plug in $y = 1$, if the degree of the equation drops below 5, then every term of $f$ contained a $y$, so $y = 0, x = $ ``anything'' is a solution.  Otherwise, you have a degree 5 equation in $z$ so it has at least one real solution.

Comment: Thanks Karl, you just beat me to it.  I'll just add that it follows for suitably generic choices of your coefficients that the solution sets (x,y,z) will be 1, 3 or 5 straight lines in $R^3$ passing through the origin.  

Comment: Karl, thanks for your answer. It would be highly appreciated if you could help on the second question just added.

Comment: Hi, unknown, I noticed that you haven't been voting up answers to any of your questions.  You should consider doing so if you find them helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Suppose otherwise and let $\mathbf{u} = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ be two linearly independent points on the hyperplane which do not intersect the quintic.  Then some point of the form $\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v} t$ must intersect the quintic because the corresponding polynomial in $t$ is of degree $5$ (in particular, its leading and constant coefficients are nonzero).

Comment: Qiaochu, thanks for the answer. It would be highly appreciated if you could also help on the second question just added.